# How to capture MS camera app preview status using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate the Microsoft camera App Preview, and return if the preview is displaying on App, using PowerShell.
`Scenario->Launch` the camera `App->verify` the Preview.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Show us what you have already tried, what failed and if you have them also the error messages you received. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.